# sqlite join 2 tables with same columns

Tags: sqlite, join

I'm trying to get a result from two sqlite tables that contain the same columns but have no other relation. Both have the `date` and `amount` columns and all I want is a new table as a result to show dates and amounts from both tables.

```
Table A
+----------+-------+
|   date   | amount|
+----------+-------+
|10-01-2013|  3.8  |
|12-23-2104|  4.2  | 
+----------+-------+
```

and

```
Table B
+----------+-------+
|   date   | amount|
+----------+-------+
|10-03-2013|  2.4  |
|12-28-2014|  3.5  |
+----------+-------+
```

And the desired table would be

```
+----------+----------+---------+
|   date   | A.amount | B.amount|
+----------+----------+---------+
|10-01-2013|    3.8   |   NULL  |
|10-03-2013|   NULL   |   2.4   |
|12-23-2104|   4.2    |   NULL  |
|12-28-2014|   NULL   |   3.5   |
+----------+----------+---------+
```

I tried many posts in the forum but I couldn't find any that match my need.

Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is not a JOIN is a UNION.

see:

[UNIONS in SQLITE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_unions_clause.htm)

Something like:

```
SELECT Date, Amount as Amount1, NULL AS Amount2
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT Date, NULL AS Amount1, Amount as Amount2
FROM TableB
```